# How do you make a correct IF statement with intervals, in Python?

Tags: python

[UPDATED CODE FURTHER DOWN with an ongoing issue]

I've recently started a course that is solely about Python through my school.
I'm a complete beginner as of today, and i just recived my first task.

**Using Python 3.10.0**

**The task was as follows:
Pretend that you're a merchant that buy cars.
A customer comes in and offers three cars for sale.**

1. Collect the following information. What brand is the car, class, year and how many miles has it driven.
2. Now make a program that summarizes the information you gathered. **As far as i have debugged in Microsoft VSC i've solved this in my own way, probably can be done in a much better way i assume though..**
   --

Though the task is graded based on how many functions or variabels you're using, the more the better in this case accordlingy to the teacher.
So i figured, why not try to make some sort of price range based on what the seller offered/answered in interval types.
Depending on what the customer gives for information regarding year and miles, in the end of this made up conversation, an automated evaluated price will be presented for all three cars based on given information.

So my question is, am i right to use the IF statement in the end of my code, if so what am i doing wrong, or isit a another solution to this?

Best Regards :)

```
q1 = input("What's the first car you'd like to offer? ")
print("Awesome! A " + q1)
q2 = input("What class is it? ")
print("Great.")
q3 = input("Year? ")
q4 = input("And lastly, how many miles have the car driven? ")

q5 = input("What's the second car you'd like to offer? ")
print("Awesome! A " + q5)
q6 = input("What class is it? ")
print("Great.")
q7 = input("Year? ")
q8 = input("And lastly, how many miles have the car driven? ")

q9 = input("What's the third car you'd like to offer? ")
print("Awesome! A " + q9)
q10 = input("What class is it? ")
print("Great.")
q11 = input("Year? ")
q12 = input("And lastly, how many miles have the car driven? ")

#Verbal summary of the offered cars.
print()
print("So we have a " + q1, "model " + q2, "year " + q3, ",that has driven " + q4, "miles.")
print("And a " + q5, "model " + q6, "year " + q7, ",that has driven " + q8, "miles.")
print("Lastly we have the cool " + q9, "model " + q10, "year " + q11, ",that has driven " + q12, "miles.")

#Calculation/Evaluation.
year_question_intervall_type_1 = 1900-1930
year_question_intervall_type_2 = 1931-1950
year_question_intervall_type_3 = 1951-1980
year_question_intervall_type_4 = 1981-2000
year_question_intervall_type_5 = 2001-2021

miles_question_interval_type_1 = 100-1000
miles_question_interval_type_2 = 1001-2000
miles_question_interval_type_3 = 2001-5000
miles_question_interval_type_4 = 5000-8000
miles_question_interval_type_5 = 8001-100000

#Price offer to seller.

if q3 == year_question_intervall_type_1: 
    print("9999 Dollars")
```

---

UPDATED CODE
Issue: #conditions menu_1
If the input is 1, it executes the way i want by triggering def menu_2 and thus conditions. And that's the end of it, and it brings a result. Don't want anything else to happen after it.

Though, if the input is 2, which is supposed to terminate the program, it keeps bringing up my def_menu2. How do i prevent that from happening?

```
#car merchant questions to customer
question_1 = input("Merchant: What car do you have to offer? ")
print("Merchant: Alright you got a " + question_1 +".")
question_2 = input("Merchant: What model isit? ")
print("Merchant: Okey..a " + question_2 +".")
question_3 = input("Merchant: Do you happen to know the year model? ")
print("Merchant: Awesome! That's a good year, " + question_3 +".")
question_4 = input("Merchant: Lastly how many kilometers has the car driven? ")
print("Merchant: Thank you. Decent numbers, " + question_4 +".")
print("")
summary_1 = ["Car: " + question_1, "Model: " + question_2, "Year: " + question_3, "Kilometers: " + question_4]
print(summary_1)
print("")

#the first menu of choices for customer
print("Merchant: I have a suggestion. Currently i have four cars available in my garage for exchange. Would you like to see the available cars?")

#menu to the first set of questions
def menu_1(): 
    print("1. Yes")
    print("2. Terminate the program")
menu_1()
option_set_one = int(input("Enter your option: "))
print("")

#conditions menu_1
while option_set_one != 0:
    if option_set_one == 1:
        #prints a list of cars available for exchange
        print("Alright! Lets have a look at my cars.")
        break
    elif option_set_one == 2:
        break
                
#menu_1 condition input 1, provides a list of four cars
cars = ["Porsche Carrera (2002)", "BMW X6 (2015)", "Volvo XC60 (2016)", "Audi A7, 2019"]
if option_set_one == 1:
    print(cars)

#menu_2 condition input 1, provides a menu for the available cars
def menu_2():
    print("1. the Porsche")
    print("2. the BMW")
    print("3. the Volvo")
    print("4. the Audi")
menu_2()
option_set_two = int(input("Which car would you like to exchange your " + question_1 + " with? "))

#conditions menu_2
while option_set_two != 0:
    if option_set_two == 1:
        print("DEAL! The Porsche is yours!")
        break
    elif option_set_two == 2:
        print("DEAL! The BMW is yours!")
        break
    elif option_set_two == 3:
        print("DEAL! The Volvo is yours!")
        break
    elif option_set_two == 4:
        print("DEAL! The Audi is yours!")
        break
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the code? Then you would see that this doesn't work.

Comment: try `if int(q3) in range (1900,1930):` you will be able for the value in the interval

Comment: @JoeFerndz Thank you Joe it helped solve the previous issue i had, i will put that to my memory. Though i've updated the code a little, tried giving it a different angle this time. 
Maybe you have an answer to my current issue on the updated code? :)

Answer (score 0):

No, this will not work because the "intervals" you assigned aren't intervals at all; they're simple integers because all you do is subtraction: `year_question_intervall_type_1 = 1900-1930` will give `-30`.

If you want to check for intervals, you could hard-code the values into an `if` statement:

```py
if 1900 <= year <= 1930:
   # do something with this information
```

Note however that you get strings from the `input()` function which you cannot directly compare to numbers. Also, be aware of the different numerical comparison operators `<` and `<=`. You probably want them to be inclusive.

To avoid hard-coding the comparison values, you could save them as tuples:

```py
year_interval1 = (1900, 1930)
```

This allows you to iterate over arbitrarily many intervals but it requires a bit more code that may be beyond the scope of your current task.

Comment: Thank you for the response Jan. I'll keep that in mind for the next time i'm gonna work with intervals. I have updated my post with some new code, similiar task with a different structure and angle.  Maybe you have some solution for my current updated issue.

Comment: @LeonSedvall please don't change the question substantially after answers were already given. Instead, you could post a new question. StackOverflow is intended to provide specific answers to direct and widely applicable questions, not as a tutoring service for individual code issues.